# force kwargs to give you the defaults back as well

Tags: python, python-3.x

An aspect of a decorator I am working on is to pull out the arguments that go into a function. How can you also make it collect the defaults?

The code at the moment is as follows:

```
def print_arguments_before_running(f):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        return f()
    return wrapper

@print_arguments_before_running
def first_function(red=5, blue=4):
    return 5
```

Then if you run it:

```
first_function(red=7)
>> {'red': 7}
>> 5
```

I want it in this case to give the output:

```
>> {'red': 7, blue: 4}
>> 5
```

Even if you give it nothing like this:

```
first_function()
```

It should still give you:

```
>> {'red': 5, blue: 4}
>> 5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python decorator to display passed AND default kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832573/python-decorator-to-display-passed-and-default-kwargs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inspect` module to get the default value information:

```
import inspect

def print_arguments_before_running(f):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        args, _, _, defaults, _, _, _ = inspect.getfullargspec(f)
        realkwargs = dict(zip(args, defaults))
        realkwargs.update(kwargs)
        print(realkwargs)

        return f()
    return wrapper
```