# Accessing the default value of kw argument in decorator?

Tags: python, arguments, python-decorators

I have the following wrapper .. the problem is I have no access to the 
default 'ret' kwargument.
It is only accessible if I pass the argument when calling the function ...

Is it possible somehow to access the default value of kw argument ?

```
    def post(fun):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          rv = fun(*args, **kwargs)
          if kwargs['ret'] == 'int' : return rv
          return [rv]
        return wrapper


    @post
    def rand(size, ret='int'):
        .....
        return randint(size)

> rand(5)
KeyError: 'ret'
> rand(5, ret='lst')
[3]
```

---

this worked so far :

```
    if 'ret' in kwargs : ret = kwargs['ret']
    else : ret = inspect.getargspec(fun).defaults[0]
```

have to make it more general..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python decorator to display passed AND default kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832573/python-decorator-to-display-passed-and-default-kwargs)

Comment: When you call the decorated `rand` function, it doesn't have a default argument as the decorator `post` returns the function `wrapper` which has the signature `(*args, **kwargs)`.  Only by inspecting `fun` (which could be `rand`, containing a default `ret` keyword argument) can the default argument be extracted (or not, if a different function was passed to `post` decorator).